# Storing distinct values in database django

Tags: django, django-models

model.py

```
class Venue(models.Model):
     venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     rent = models.IntegerField()
     parking_area = models.IntegerField()
     picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.venue_Name
```

I want to create another model that stores the only distinct value of place from the Venue class

Comment: why would you want to do that ? If you need the distinct places, just do a query on `Venue` for unique places.

Comment: could u get me that code i am not familiar with query in django

Comment: and i need to do something like thishttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186928/jquery-to-filter-the-content-being-printed-in-the-template-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the distinct places, just do a distinct query:

```
Venue.objects.values_list('place', flat=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple query to get the distinct places:

you can get all venue objects with

```
Venue.objects.all()
```

So you can filter the places using:

```
def Distinct_Places():
    distinct_places = []
    for v in Venue.objects.all():
        if v.place not in distinct_places:
            distinct_places.append(v.place)
    return distinct_places
```

Hope it helps.

**Hint**

You may also want to take a look of [Distinct QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)