# jquery to filter the content being printed in the template django

Tags: jquery, django

template.html

```
  <select>
  {% for place in places %}
  <option value="{{place.name}}">{{place.name}}</option>
    {% endfor%}
 </select>
{% for venue in venues %}
<div class="homeimgbox_services">
  <img src="{{  venue.picture.url }}" width="431" height="187" class="img_inner fservices fl2">
  <div class="font_ins_box_hotel">
    <input type="radio" name="venue" id="venue{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{  venue.rent }}">
    <label for="venue{{ forloop.counter }}"></label>
    {{venue.venue_Name}}        </div>
  <div class="font_ins_box_addr">
      {{ venue.place }}<br>parking:{{ venue.parking_area }}</div>
  <div class="font_ins_box_rupees">
   Rs {{ venue.rent }}     </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
    {% endfor %}
<div >
```

I want to filter this with value place being selected in the drop down list when a button is pressed

Comment: Do you mean filter venue which venue.place match the place selected on the `<select>` ? I guess that becaouse your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186725/storing-distinct-values-in-database-django)

Comment: yes filter venue with venue.place

Comment: if you want to do it dynamically you need to use javascript.

Comment: can u get me javascript code

Comment: There are **A LOT WAYS** to get that behavior using JavaScript, I **advise** use any framework for your sites. Here some of them: [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org), [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com), [angularjs](http://angularjs.org), [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/)